# failed to create task or type propertyfile: Ant build

Tags: ant

Hi I am facing this problem while building a source using ant

---

Problem: failed to create task or type propertyfile
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib

---

I am not able to figure out which additional component of ant is missing i did yum install the latest ant package.

Could some one help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class is in `ant-nodeps.jar` in your ant_home/lib. Check you have the right jar

Comment: hi I copied teh ant-nodes.jar to the folder usr/share/ant/lib but still no change ...i dono what to do next

Comment: Yes still the same error .... I also thought may be becoz the other jars in the usr/share/ant/lib folder are sym links to  jars in the sr/share/java/ folder I should also make sym links but still it didnt work.

Comment: so what was the resolution of the problem?

Comment: I had to install `ant-optional` package `sudo apt-get install ant-optional`